# ajax combobox not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Ajax comboBox control is not rendering properly and going in front of other controls. When i click on menu which is (li) tag and menu goes behind th ajax combo box.

[image]

**Here is ajax combo box CSS i am using**

```
.WindowsStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer input
{
margin: 0;
border: solid 1px #7F9DB9;
border-right: 0px none;
padding: 1px 0px 0px 5px;
font-size: 13px;
height: 18px;
}
.WindowsStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: url(/images/AJAX/windows-arrow.gif);
background-position: top left;
border: 0px none;
height: 21px;
width: 21px;
}

.WindowsStyle .ajax__combobox_itemlist
{
border-color: #7F9DB9;
}
```

Is there anythinf to do with ajax css i am using?

**Here is menu css**

```
{
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #069;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
```

}

Comment: you need to set z-index of menu

Comment: but why menu works fine with asp.net controls?

Comment: @user1263981, Check explanation for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**z-index** is a CSS property that sets the stack order of specific elements. An element with greater stack order is always in front of another element with lower stack order.

To know more about it check this link : [Z-index](http://www.cssmojo.com/everything_you_always_wanted_to_know_about_z-index_but_were_afraid_to_ask/)

css for menu :

```
{
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #069;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 6px;

  // Add this line to your menu Css.
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

OR

change the z-index of your ajax control, but here we will decrease the stack order to lower side to keep the control at the back of the menu. if -1 does not help you can still lower down the value of your z-index for the control.

```
WindowsStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer input
{
margin: 0;
border: solid 1px #7F9DB9;
border-right: 0px none;
padding: 1px 0px 0px 5px;
font-size: 13px;
height: 18px;

// Add this line to your menu Css.
  z-index: -1;
}
```

> I would suggest you, is to inspect the form from browser and check
>   what is the best z-index for you. and then set it

Comment: Thanks it is working fine now but it works fine with other asp.net control without defining z-index?

Comment: I've placed a link in my answer to know why its works with other controls and not with few controls. If that answer helped please select it as answer, that would help others in future.

Comment: is there any way to put ajax combo behind other controls as i can't use z-index with menu because i have many other pop up control which would go behind the menu item.

Comment: z-index: -1 for combobox?

Comment: exactly, z-index to -1 will work for you, or you can still lower down the value of z-index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56102/discussion-between-user1263981-and-krunal-patil).